# ASP.NET Core MVCで、複数ボタンを区別するには？

Tags: c#, html5, asp.net

ASP.NET Core(2.1) MVCでWebアプリを構築しています。

[複数ボタンのあるFormで押されたボタンを判断する](https://qiita.com/echoprogress/items/17e85ad489bddf07b540)

上記サイトの「セレクター属性を作成する」を参考に、Viewに複数ボタンを配置し、アクションメソッドを区別するということをやりたいと思っていますが、ASP.NET Core(2.1) ではIsValidForRequestの引数が変わっており、同様のことが実現できません。

ご教授いただけないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

セレクター属性のコードを、以下のように変更すれば動作します。

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Abstractions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ActionConstraints;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing;

namespace test.Extensions
{
    public class ButtonAttribute: ActionMethodSelectorAttribute
    {
        // アクションメソッド付加時に設定したボタン名を保存
        public string ButtonName { get; set; }

        public override bool IsValidForRequest(RouteContext routeContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescripter)
        {
            // 設定したボタン名と同名のデータが存在するかチェック（Requestで返ってきているか）
            return routeContext.HttpContext.Request.HasFormContentType && 
                routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys.Contains(ButtonName);
        }        
    }
}
```

しかし、HTML5の`input`の`formaction`属性で送信先のURLを設定できるので、こちらを使った方が簡単です。`form`タグの`action`よりも`formaction`の方が優先します。
ビューのコードは、

```
<form method="post">
     @*テキストボックス等の入力項目の設定*@

    <input type="submit" formaction="/Home/Search" name="Search" value="検索">
    <input type="submit" formaction="/Home/Clear" name="Clear" value="クリア">
</form>
```

又は、Tag Helpersを使うと、

```
<form method="post">
     @*テキストボックス等の入力項目の設定*@

    <input type="submit" asp-action="Search" name="Search" value="検索">
    <input type="submit" asp-action="Clear" name="Clear" value="クリア">
</form>
```

コントローラーのコードは、

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Search()
{
    // 検索ボタンが押された場合の処理
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Clear()
{
    // クリアボタンが押された場合の処理
}
```

Comment: 早速の回答ありがとうございます。  「セレクター属性のコードを、以下のように変更すれば動作します。」を試しましたが、「routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys = 'routeContext.HttpContext.Request.Form.Keys' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'」のエラーになります。  何かお分かりになればご教授いただけないでしょうか。  「formaction」はブラウザがHTML5に対応していないため、残念ながら使用できないようです。

Comment: formactionはIE10以降には対応しています。古いブラウザーの対応作業お疲れ様です。Formがnullのときにエラーになるので回答を修正しました。

Comment: うまく行きました！IE7対応で苦戦していました。  すごくうれしいです^^  ありがとうございました。

Comment: うまく行ったら、回答の横にあるチェックマークをクリックしてグレー表示からチェック済みに切り替えておいてください。