# Form内にボタンを２つ設置し、各々別の処理をさせたい。

Tags: html, laravel

Form内にボタンを２つ設置し、各々別の処理（action）をさせることって可能ですか？
以下LaravelのBladeです。

例えば Next を教えたときに `action method.a` 、Finish で `action method.b` を実行させるという具合です。

```
<form method="post" action={{ route('method.a')}}>
    @csrf                
            <input type="hidden" name="id" value = "{{$id}}" >                     
            <textarea type="textarea" class = "textarea" id="item" name="itemList"></textarea>
                <br/>
              
                ：<input type="text" id = "sss" name="sss" value =""> 
                ：<input type="text" id = "ppp" name="ppp" value =""> 
                <button type="submit" class="button">Next</button>
                <br/>
            <button type="submit" class="button">Finish</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: サーバサイドの言語は違いますが、HTML部分はおそらく参考になるかと　https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/47925/

Answer (score 1):

別の方が既に書かれている通りactionを切り替える場合 `formaction`  が使える他、actionが同じだった場合は `<button name="foo" value="bar">barボタン</button>` みたいな感じでどのボタンが押されたのかサーバ側で受け取れる（これで処理を切り替えられる）ので、これら適宜使い分けると良いです。

ちなみにどちらの方法を使う場合も **ボタンクリックではなくエンターキー押下でsubmitされた場合** に注意して下さい。多くのブラウザは「form中に最初に現れたボタンがsubmitされたと見做す」という動作になってますがそれはおそらくユーザーの意図する挙動ではないので、これに該当する場合エンターキーによるsubmitを抑制する対応が必要です。

Answer (score 0):

buttonタグにformaction属性をつけると良いのではないでしょうか。

以下のページなどが参考になると思います。

[html5 で導入された button タグに付けれる formaction と formtarget 属性 を用いてプレビューを実現する](https://qiita.com/yamotuki/items/e394bcc38614c091c7fd)